# How do I load an mp3 from raw using Uri.parse in android?

Tags: android, uri, android-mediaplayer

How do I load an mp3 from raw using Uri.parse? The variable `name` is a string (such as `fun` (if the file was fun.mp3)). When I try to play an audio file from raw, but receive a null object reference error. I'm probably missing something uber simple. Thanks.

```
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("R.raw." + name));
    player.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I load an mp3 from raw using Uri.parse?

You don't, usually.

> When I try to play an audio file from raw, but receive a null object reference error.

Among other things, that is not a valid string to parse as a `Uri`.

Use the `create()` method that takes the raw resource ID as an `int` parameter. If your problem is that you do not have that `int`, use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to look it up by name.

Comment: Oh derp, that makes sense. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong way either do this

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.name);
    player.start();
```

Or do this way:

```
int resID = myContext.getResources().getIdentifier("name","raw",myContext.getPackageName());

player = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);
    player.start();
```